# Flutter: Favourite item in listview

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add a favourite button to list view, all it needs to be is an icon on the end of each list item that you can tap to change the colour of it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './images.dart';

class LikedList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LikedListState createState() => _LikedListState();
}

class _LikedListState extends State<LikedList> {
  List<bool> _likes = [];

  Color _iconColor = Colors.grey[700];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Liked List'),
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
        itemCount: ImagesState.likes.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final item = ImagesState.likes[index];
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(item),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: _likes[index]
                  ? Icon(
                      Icons.favorite_border,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    )
                  : Icon(
                      Icons.favorite,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _likes[index] = !_likes[index];
                });
              },
            ),
            onLongPress: () {
              setState(() {
                print(ImagesState.likes[index]);
                ImagesState.likes.removeAt(index);
              });
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, this is resulting in:

```
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your _likes list is Empty. 
Initialize your _likes list with boolean values as per ypur total items of list you are showing.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: I'm saying that at which place your are putting values in your list of _likes??? That you are changing on onPressed.